# Flv streaming video on website via jwplayer does not play on android iphone

Tags: php, android, iphone, video-streaming, jwplayer

Hi I tried ustream and it plays well on my android 2.2.
Now I intend to use live streaming via jwplayer which unfortunately does not work on iphone or android.
Flv streaming video on website via jwplayer does not play on android iphone

Answer (score 0):

need some css tweak because default CSSs works for desktop browsers you have to include desired css for mobile